# Prompt a local file like Open SaveAs from browser

Tags: file, browser, dialog

I have a file in my local system. I would like to know how to take it to browser and prompting open, save as, cancel dialog as similar while downloading a file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank god. I fixed it using the below code. "filename" is the name of the  file and "filepath" is the physical location of the file.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/x-7z-compressed";
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ".zip");              
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(filepath);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```